# Extracting values from data in JSON format in python 3.x

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, dictionary

I have some experience in programming in python but fairly limited in how to handle large data.
I tried looking if someone had asked similar questions, but did only find examples where the data wasn't as "nested" as this example. If it has already been asked or documented elsewhere please point me in that direciton.

What I have done:
I have accessed the API for the local weather station and retrieved the data in JSON format with 'request.get'.
I have managed to print out the data, but I have difficulties understanding how to retrieve specific values inside the dictionary.

What I try to do:
I want to retrieve the "air_temperature" value for the current hour and only print the timestamp and the air_temperature value. I want to do some other things as well, but if I understand how to retrieve these specific values I should figure the rest out for my self.

Example code:

```
import requests
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0'


parameters = {
    "lat": 40.416695,
    "lon": 8.306090,
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params= parameters)


#This loop was an attempt of trying to sort out the relevant data, but all the values in the 'properties' key got bunched together and I cant figure out how to access specific data
for key, value in response.json().items():   
    print(key)
    print(type(key), "key \n \n")
    print(value)
    print(type(value), "value \n \n")

#pseudocode of what I want to do:
for i = 0 to length(response.json().properties.timeseries)
    if response.json().properties.timeseries[i].time = "2023-01-29T09:00:00Z"
       print("timestamp: ", response.json().properties.timeseries[i].time, "temperature: ", response.json().properties.timeseries[i].data.instant.details.air_temperature)
```

Example of the data can be found on this web page:
https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the first air_temperatur and time from the returned data:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact'
parameters = {
    "lat": 40.416695,
    "lon": 8.306090,
}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0'}

data = requests.get(url, params=parameters, headers=headers).json()

current = data['properties']['timeseries'][0]
print(current['time'], current['data']['instant']['details']['air_temperature'])
```

Prints:

```
2023-01-29T10:00:00Z 10.8
```